# Examples where estimating the derivative is easier than estimating the actual quantity.

Tags: calculus, soft-question, parameter-estimation

I recently came across a paper in which they author estimated the deriviative of the quanity he was interested in rather than the quantity itself.  This was done because apparntly the derivative estimate is much more accurate.  I have never seen such a scenerio before. Are there other examples where this is generally true?

Comment: What paper are you referring to?

Comment: @user458276 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6216948